# (selenium) why all elements looks same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to convert all my steam game-hours to pandas dataframe, but i am getting output like below, all games and hours looks like same. is there any mistake that i made in the code if so, how can i fix it?

output:

```
title                 hour
0    The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
1    The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
2    The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
3    The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
4    The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
..                        ...                  ...
312  The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
313  The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
314  The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
315  The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat
316  The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt  kayıtlarda 137 saat

[317 rows x 2 columns]
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/username/games/?tab=all'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="path/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
game_hour_infos = []
games = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gameListRow')
for game in games:

    title = game.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[starts-with(@id,"game_")]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div').text
    hour = game.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[starts-with(@id,"game_")]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h5').text
    ghi = {
        "title": title,
        "hour": hour
    }

    game_hour_infos.append(ghi)


print(pd.DataFrame(game_hour_infos))
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to find element within element, put a `.` at the beginning of the xpath.  Try like below:

```
games = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gameListRow")

for game in games:
    title = game.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"gameListRowItemName")]').text
    hour = game.find_element_by_xpath('.//h5[contains(@class,"hours_played")]').text

    print(f"{title} : {hour}")
```